# How to find constants to show $an+b = O(n^2)$?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

In the Introduction to Algorithms textbook by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest and Stein, it says that "When $a>0$, any linear function $an+b$ is in $O(n^2)$, which can be easily verified by taking $c = a +|b|$ and $n_0 = \text{max}(1, -b/a)$. I understand that any linear function is in $O(n^2)$. But I don't understand how they come up with the $c$ and $n_0$.

In this CLRS textbook, the definition of big-Oh notation is:

$O(g(n)) = \{f(n): \text{there exist positive constants } c \text{ and } n_0 \text{ such that } 0\le f(n)\le cg(n) \text{ for all } n\ge n_0\}$

Question: How can I derive the expressions for $c$ and $n_0$?

Thank you!

Comment: If $n>a,n^2> b$ then $an+b<n^2+n^2=2n^2$.

Comment: I am reading other lectures and from what I've read a linear function is O(n) and not O(n^2). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Are you sure it was big O? A linear function is in O(n^k) for all k >= 1 because O is used for the upper bound. On the other hand, a linear function is not Omega or Theta (n^2).

Comment: @ErockBrox Linear functions are both $O(n)$ and $O(n^2)$, since the set of $O(n)$ functions is contained in the set of $O(n^2)$ functions.  Just because $f$ is "big O of something" doesn't mean it can't also be "big O of something else".  See my answer below for an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of $O(n^2)$ as a set of functions.  It is the set of functions $f$ for which there is a constant $c$ such that $f(n)\le cn^2$ for every $n$ large enough.  In other words, $O(n^2)$ is the set of functions that asymptotically grow at most as fast as a quadratic.

Similarly, $O(n)$ is the set of functions $f$ for which there is a constant $c$ such that $f(n)\le cn$ for every $n$ large enough.  However,  from this you can see that any function that is $O(n)$ is also $O(n^2)$.  So in other words, if a function $f$ is $O(n)$, then $f$ is also $O(n^2)$.

In fact, if $f$ is $O(n^k)$, then $f$ is also $O(n^l)$ for any $l \geq k$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do understand the big-Oh notation being the set. Also I am more comfortable with the big-Oh notation defined in terms of limit. I am concerned about how the authors derived the expressions for $c$ and $n_0$.

Comment: Unfortunately, "the big-Oh notation defined in terms of limit", to which the OP refers to in the previous comment, and which this answer was using, is quite wrong. I edited the answer to make it mathematically correct.

Comment: @Did Why do you think big-O in terms of limits is wrong?  The definition I originally had written is mathematically equivalent to the one you changed my answer to.

Comment: Certainly not. The first version involved possibly non existent quantities such as $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{n^2}$ while the current version, carefully avoiding to mention limits where there might be none, is mathematically rigorous. As an example, if $f(n)=2n^2+(-1)^nn^2$ then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{n^2}$ does not exist since $\frac{f(n)}{n^2}$ has two limit points (namely, $1$ and $3$) but $f(n)=O(n^2)$ (and even, $f(n)=\Theta(n^2)$).

Comment: @Did Fair enough, it is true that I assumed the existence of the limit.  One can always use the limsup to cover these kinds of cases (of course taking values in the extended reals).  While the use of limits certainly introduces some technical considerations, I think that conceptually they are quite useful for an elementary understanding of 'big-O' or any sort of asymptotic behavior.  While admittedly oversimplified, I would hardly say that my original explanation was 'quite wrong'.

Comment: Sorry but it is crucial to understand that the sequence $(x_n)$ defined by $x_{2n}=n$, $x_{2n+1}=0$, is $O(n)$. Every "simplified" "definition" failing this should be abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:
b is positive (remember our assumption is a > 0) so f(n) is asymptotically non-negative function.
assume n > 1
now f(n)/g(n) = (a*n + b)/n^2 < (a*n^2 + b*n^2)/n^2 < (a + b)

Case2: 
b is negative and |b| > a
then f(n) to be asymptotically non-negative function n > -b/a (at n=-b/a f(n) will be 0)
so assume n > -b/a
now f(n)/g(n) = (a*n + b)/n^2 < (a*n^2 + |b|*n^2)/n^2 < (a + |b|)

therefore, 
c = a + |b| and n0 = max(1,-b/a)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).